# AEM 6.2 - Custom workflow step not working

Tags: servlets, adobe, workflow, aem

I created a custom workflow step but the issue is it doesn't show up in the list when I try to add it to a new workflow.

I've followed guides and done everything as described to no avail.

There are no error messages that I can find.

In the web console, I can see my bundle. It is being updated correctly every time I install it, BUT, while my workflow package is visible, the service itself is not visible. So, it looks like it's not being loaded for some reason.

Note: Maybe unrelated but servlets that use a "path" don't work either (they're not visible in the bundle in the console). The example servlet that comes with the AEM archetype works fine however but works differently (it uses the resourceType instead of a path).

Also, in Eclipse, it says the Felix scr annotations are deprecated and they have a line through them. I don't use eclipse for the build and install so I'm not sure that's the issue, but I thought it was worth mentioning.

Thanks

Edit - Here's some example code:

```
package company.aem.core.workflow;

import javax.jcr.Node;
import javax.jcr.NodeIterator;
import javax.jcr.RepositoryException;
import javax.jcr.Session;
import javax.jcr.Workspace;

import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component; // <--- shows up as deprecated
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;// <--- shows up as deprecated
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;// <--- shows up as deprecated
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;// <--- shows up as deprecated
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;

import com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowException;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkItem;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.exec.WorkflowProcess;
import com.adobe.granite.workflow.metadata.MetaDataMap;

@Component // <----- this shows up as deprecated in eclipse
@Service // <----- this shows up as deprecated in eclipse
public class CommunityObjectsDeploymentWorkflow implements WorkflowProcess {

    @Property(value = "Test workflow implementation") // <----- this shows up as deprecated in eclipse
    static final String DESCRIPTION = Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION; 
    @Property(value = "Some vendor") // <----- this shows up as deprecated in eclipse
    static final String VENDOR = Constants.SERVICE_VENDOR;
    @Property(value = "My Sample Workflow Process") // <----- this shows up as deprecated in eclipse
    static final String LABEL="My test workflow";

    @Override
    public void execute(WorkItem workItem, WorkflowSession workflowSession, MetaDataMap metaDataMap) throws WorkflowException {

        Session session = (Session) workflowSession.adaptTo(Session.class);
        Workspace workspace = session.getWorkspace();

        try {
            // do JCR related stuff
        } catch (RepositoryException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

### Edit: The solution was to choose the correct component annotation import.

Change this:

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
```

To this:

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
```

Now the service is running, and visible in the web console.

Note: Even though the other annotations are technically deprecated, they still work. It looks like only the Component one needed to change.

And for it to be visible in the process editor, it needs the **process.label** property (using the Property annotation in the Felix package) like so:

```
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
@Property(value = "My Sample Workflow Process")
    static final String LABEL="process.label";
```

Answer (score 2):

Any workflow process needs a property with name ***process.label*** to be shown in the list of processes for a workflow step.
This property is missing in the given sample code.

On another note on the deprecation warning for the Apache Felix SCR annotations. These annotations have been deprecated in favour of the standard OSGi Declarative Services annotations.

Comment: The thing is, the service doesn't even show up in the web console which makes me think it isn't even running. So the label shouldn't make any difference.
Is there any documentation for use of the OSGi Declaractive Services annotations with AEM? Every single example I find about making AEM services/components use the Felix SCR annotations. I can't find any examples of the one you mentioned. The syntax is different enough that I can't declare the label or description or anything like that in the usual way.

Comment: I've updated my original post with the solution. You mentioning the OSGi Declarative Services put on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've updated the original post with more details. The problem was the @Component annotation import. I was using the Felix one. I changed it to the OSGi one that appears as an option in Eclipse and that worked.

As an aside, For the custom workflow step to appear in the workflow editor, you also need to have a **process.label** property. My original code didn't have that but I've changed it and now its visible there too.